# Is there any way to acquire a connection from session pool with SYSDBA privileges?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

When connecting using cx_oracle.connect there is a parameter

```
mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA
```

but I could not find any way of specifying the same with session_pool

when I try to give session_pool to connect

```
db_pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool('', '', db_alias, min=1, max=20, increment=1, homogeneous=False)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect('test1',
                                 'test1',
                                 db_alias,
                                 mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA,
                                 pool=db_pool)
```

it throws an error ORA-24300: bad value for mode.

I'm using 6.4.1 version of cx_oracle

Is there any way to acquire a connection from session pool with SYSDBA privileges?